# ASP Classic web page length limit

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, windows-xp

I have an  ASP classic web application running on windows 2008 r2  server is not rendering  the whole page(only last 70 % is shown)  while  the same application on my localhost running xp shows all the page content.

Is there any limit on the web page size on new iis or is there any property to change on iis to fit all the page  size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  fixed the issue by increasing the  IIS download size  to the  size of my page (approximated  size by saving the page to local)